# gvim 8.2 doesn't redraw the screen when editing a git commit message in windows 10 powershell

Tags: windows-10, vim, gvim, powershell-5.0

I installed `vim` on windows 10 using [`chocolatey`](https://chocolatey.org/). When I edit a file in powershell, everything works great! [I even got copy and paste to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62619756/9636). However, when I edit a git commit message, `vim` doesn't redraw my screen properly. If I [force a screen redraw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1117731/9636), I can see my updated text properly, but that is super annoying.

I configured `git` to use `vim` with:

```
git config --global core.editor vim
```

How can I make `vim` behave properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git for Windows ships its own version of Vim as part of the distribution.  This is because there needs to be a default editor, and the default editor for Unix programs like Git is usually `vi`.

When you specify the editor as `vim`, the version that's being used is the version that's first in `PATH`, which is probably the Git for Windows version if you haven't specified that your custom version is to be used.  That version of Vim probably wants the `TERM` environment variable to be set to tell it what terminal type to use, and since it's not, it doesn't render properly.  If you're using the Microsoft Terminal implementation, you probably want to use `xterm-256color` as the value for the `TERM` environment variable.

If you want to use your custom Vim version, such as the one installed by Chocolatey, then it needs to either be earlier in `PATH` or you need to specify the full path.  Git passes the value of the `core.editor` configuration option to the shell, so your command needs to meet the syntax for a POSIX `sh` implementation, where backslash is an escape character.  You therefore either want to use forward slashes or single quotes around the name of the program.

If your version of Vim is graphical, then you need the `-f` option so that it does not detach from the terminal.  Otherwise, Vim starts and immediately detaches from the terminal, so Git sees the process it spawned immediately exit.  Since that process (your editor) has exited, Git assumes that you're done editing.  But since you didn't actually edit anything, Git aborts your commit.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR**

Giving git the direct fully-qualified path to my vim executable fixed things, and I don't know why:

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:\tools\vim\vim82\vim.exe' -f -i NONE"
```

Single quotes around the path are important because `git` doesn't know how to handle paths with backslashes.
Double quotes around the whole configuration are important so that git doesn't apply `-f -f NONE` to the `git config` command.
I found `-f -i NONE` on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28952307/9636), and I don't know what it does, but `git commit` didn't work without it.

**How I found the full path**

`vim` adds a `c:\windows\vim.bat` file, which is what `powershell` uses to launch `vim` when you type `vim`:

```
PS C:\Users\heath> Get-Command vim

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     vim.bat                                            0.0.0.0    C:\windows\vim.bat
```

`vim.bat` is pretty simple:

```
@echo off
rem -- Run Vim --
rem # uninstall key: vim82 #

setlocal
set VIM_EXE_DIR=C:\tools\vim\vim82
if exist "%VIM%\vim82\vim.exe" set VIM_EXE_DIR=%VIM%\vim82
if exist "%VIMRUNTIME%\vim.exe" set VIM_EXE_DIR=%VIMRUNTIME%

if not exist "%VIM_EXE_DIR%\vim.exe" (
    echo "%VIM_EXE_DIR%\vim.exe" not found
    goto :eof
)

"%VIM_EXE_DIR%\vim.exe"  %*
```

Thus, my full `vim` path is `C:\tools\vim\vim82\vim.exe`